# Relation of user to user_role is not working right

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, spring-boot

In my Role model I have this model:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "role")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

And in my User model I have this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = true)
private Role role;
```

So a user can have 1 role and a role can have many users. However when I add a role to a user and I run the API the JSON array adds all users to a row. What am I doing wrong?

Sample:

> [{"id":4,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{"id":12,"role":{"id":1,"users":[{..."

What I am trying to accomplish is the user to have instead of the "role_id" column a "role" column with the name value of role as its' value.

So like

User: John, Doe, 1

Becomes

User: John, Doe, Boss